# HTML video works locally, but not on the AZURE server

Tags: azure, mime-types, file-extension

New to the server side and stuck...

I have a short video clip on my website.  Locally, it working in the browser.  Then I deployed to Azure and the video didn't work.  My HTML is:

```
<section class="promo static" id="home">
  <video autoplay="" loop="" poster="assets/img/VideoPick.png" id="bgvid">
    <source src="assets/img/ThisVideo.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="assets/img/ThisVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</section>
```

Note: My local is a Mac, and I am using sublime for the editor.

Is there something in the configurations I need to change, or a web.config file that I need to add and reference in the project?

Answer (score 10):

You need to allow mp4 on IIS. You can do this using a web.config file.

PS: you don't need to use .NET, just create a file called "web.config" with the following content:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".webm" mimeType="video/webm" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Do I need to reference the web.config anywhere, or does it just need to live in the project folder?

Comment: just upload the web.config to root of the website (using ftp for example)